# Problem when validating numbers 1, 2, and 3

Tags: javascript, validation, while-loop

I'm currently working on an assignment where a person must choose cave 1, 2 or 3. Everything works except the validation part. This function is used to see if the user put in a number lower than 1, higher than 3 or not even a number. I'm trying to use a while loop to fix my problem. I have tried putting a continue after between the third last and second brackets.

```
//Gets input from the user
guess = prompt("Which cave will you go in? 1, 2 or 3?");
valid(guess);

//Checks if the input is valid
function valid(number) {
    while(isNaN(number) || number < 1 || number > 3){
        alert("Please Try Again");
        prompt("Which cave will you go in? 1, 2 or 3?");
        if(number <= 1 || number >= 3){
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: in the function, you are never getting the value returned by `prompt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the `prompt` input in the function. Here is the solution with some modifications:

```js
//Gets input from the user
guess = prompt("Which cave will you go in? 1, 2 or 3?");
valid(guess);

//Checks if the input is valid
function valid(number) {
    let guess = number;
    while(isNaN(guess) || guess < 1 || guess > 3){
        alert("Please Try Again");
        guess = prompt("Which cave will you go in? 1, 2 or 3?");
        if(!isNaN(guess) && guess <= 1 && guess >= 3){
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the second prompt return value in a variable.

Also, return value of `prompt` is always a string, so you need to parse it into an int too for proper comparison, although JS implicitly converts it for you.

```
//Gets input from the user
guess = parseInt(prompt("Which cave will you go in? 1, 2 or 3?"));
valid(guess);

//Checks if the input is valid
function valid(number) {
    while(isNaN(number) || number < 1 || number > 3){
        alert("Please Try Again");
        let number = parseInt(prompt("Which cave will you go in? 1, 2 or 3?"));
        if(number <= 1 || number >= 3){
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line `valid(guess);` to `valid(parseInt(guess));`